# How to name JSON Array from Arraylist

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am having some trouble in grouping a JSON return.

I need to give the array group a name.

I've found a lot of information online but it keeps confusing me.
I haven't got a lot of experience in this so any help is useful.

Thanks for the input!

Here's my code:

```
    public ArrayList Get()
    {
        ArrayList objs = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            FIREBIRD.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Firebird"].ConnectionString;
            FIREBIRD.Open();

            FbDataReader reader = null;
            FbCommand command = new FbCommand("SOME QUERY", FIREBIRD);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    objs.Add(new
                    {
                        id = reader["CODE"],
                        name = reader["TITE"],
                        address = reader["ADRES"],
                        postal_code = reader["POSTAL"],
                        city = reader["CITY"]
                    });
                }
                return objs;
            }
            else
            {
                objs.Add(new { ERROR = "NO DATA AVAILABLE" });
                return objs;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            FIREBIRD.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The current return:

```
[{
    "id": "code",
    "name": "name",
    "address": "adres",
    "postal_code": "1234",
    "city": "city"
}]
```

What it should return:

```
{"sites":
[{
    "id": "code",
    "name": "name",
    "address": "adres",
    "postal_code": "1234",
    "city": "city"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have an object, so the `Get` method should return an object instead of `ArrayList`. When that's done, you will need to

```
return new {
    sites = objs;
}
```

instead of

```
return objs;
```

EDIT

```
public Object Get()
{
    ArrayList objs = new ArrayList();

    try
    {
        FIREBIRD.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Firebird"].ConnectionString;
        FIREBIRD.Open();

        FbDataReader reader = null;
        FbCommand command = new FbCommand("SOME QUERY", FIREBIRD);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                objs.Add(new
                {
                    id = reader["CODE"],
                    name = reader["TITE"],
                    address = reader["ADRES"],
                    postal_code = reader["POSTAL"],
                    city = reader["CITY"]
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objs.Add(new { ERROR = "NO DATA AVAILABLE" });
        }
        return new {
            sites = objs;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    finally
    {
        FIREBIRD.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Lajos Arpad, first of all: thank you for your reply. But i'm not following here. Should I change the way I nest the items or?

Comment: @Gregory you are welcome. Your code is almost good as it is. Just change returns objs; to my recommendation and make sure that you return an object with your Get method. You need a wrapper around objs.

Comment: @Gregory please take a look at my edited answer. It is untested, but quite shows what I am suggesting.

Comment: @Gregory I'm glad that the problem has been solved.